# SSIS get latest file from folder based on date/time and Name

Tags: vbscript, ssis

I have the following script which returns latest file from a folder, but I have an issue where there are 2 files created practically at same time and I need to make sure I only select a specific 1 for example

File 1 = Name "Open 12345"

File 2 = Name "Close 12345"

File 2 was created 10 secs after File 1 so, it is the latest but I need to ignore and only retrieve file 1, and just to throw a spanner in the works the numbers after the filename are random so I need to just match on first part of name only

Code used at moment

```
 Public Sub Main()

    Dim recentFile
    Dim fi As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim fis() As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("\\Test Folder\")

    fis = dir.GetFiles()
    For Each fi In fis
        If (recentFile Is Nothing) Then
            recentFile = fi
        ElseIf (recentFile.LastWriteTime < fi.LastWriteTime) Then
            recentFile = fi
        End If
    Next

    recentFile.CopyTo("\\Test Folder\Import\Open.xls")
    '
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub
```

help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Thinks I've answered it myself by inserting a check

If Mid(fi.Name, 1, 4) = "Open" this could be any name just adjust the length (4) to match length of text for comparison

so this section becomes

```
For Each fi In fis
 If Mid(fi.Name, 1, 4) = "Open" Then
    If (recentFile Is Nothing) Then
        recentFile = fi
    ElseIf (recentFile.LastWriteTime < fi.LastWriteTime) Then
        recentFile = fi
    End If
 end if
Next
```